# MySQL FullText search?

Tags: mysql, database, search, full-text-search

I am working on search functionality in my website. I want to provide a best search mechanism to users. I am using PHP/MYSQL.

Let's say user searched for "sport".

I have 30 records having word "sport" and 5 records having word "sports" but when I am searching for sport then following query only returns the result 30 who have the word "sport". But actually I think the best way to provide good search result is to display all the 30+5 records, all the records having sport or sports.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.title, p.descr, p.tags FROM pdata p WHERE MATCH (p.title, p.tags, p.descr) AGAINST ('sport')
```

Please tell me some articles or some tips & tricks using which I'll be able to provide a good search functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```
...MATCH (p.title, p.tags, p.descr) AGAINST ('sport*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

May do the trick.

Edit, the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) is an excellent resource for these kind of problems! :)

Comment: Hit the target :) wow. Hey its working perfect. But I am not getting why it was not giving me data before (without * and IN BOOLEAN MODE keyword) ?? Please tell me.

Comment: But getting one more problem.. When I am searching for AGAINST ('ipl*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) then its returning only one result whereas I have arround 5 records which have "ipl" word in title, tags and descr columns. Then why its only returning one result. and when I am searching "ICL" then its returning 0 results whereas I have one record which have ICL in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the % wildcard on your search strings. This will allow any words formed by the search string to be matched. Sadly you will need to be in Boolean mode for this wildcard to work. Also all search strings must be greater then 3 characters in order to show up using full text search. this can be changed in the mysql system settings, but the default is 3.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would make the following query:

> SELECT p.id, p.title, p.descr, p.tags
>   FROM pdata p WHERE (p.title LIKE
>   '%SPORT%' OR p.tags LIKE '%SPORT%' OR
>   p.descr LIKE'%SPORT%')

This query would find any articles which cover sportmagazines , summer-sports ect ect.